# Code to accept 32byte hex password

Tags: python, hash

I'm doing some experiment with the following code:

```
import hashlib
password = 16 
n = 2 #counter
hash = hashlib.sha256(str(password) + str(n)).hexdigest() #will read the password as string and hash
print hash
```

What should be the proper code so it can accept a 32byte hex like 000000...0002?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hex in Python is just a fancy way of writing an integer. So simply set `password` to your hex value:

```
password = 0x00000000000000000000000000000002
```